# Passing website content to URL parameter on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Can someone enlighten me how this is done?

On [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okduv.png) you see a table like layout to inform which course is taking place when and at what time (it's from a school website). At the end it has a link with "schrijf nu in" which means "enlist now".

That links sends you to a contact form seen in [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHRLf.png). What I can't figure out is how they manage to pre-populate the fields according to the course you selected.

I understand this is passed through the URL, but I highly doubt they hard-coded the keys and values in the link tag like this:

```html
<a href="www.test.com/randompage?course=english">Click me</a>
```

It must work with some kind of variable right? Because they can never know how many classes they will be having at a certain moment?

I'm trying to build something similar on Wordpress where I create a custom post type for the different courses and classes and then display a loop on the frontpage to recreate the table like layout seen in "image 1".

But I'm stuck with the "enlist now" button that links to the contact form.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You may do like this.
<a href="www.test.com/randompage?courseID=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Click me</a>

This will open randompage with the ID as param. and there you can fetch data of given ID from database.

Comment: That returns me something like: www.test.com/randompage?courseID=<?php%20echo%20get_the_ID();%20?> it doesn't seem to parse the php?

Comment: It means you are not writing in .php file. That's why php code is not parsing.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be like this

in first page

`<a href='/contact.php?id=12&title="Hello World"&content=SomeCOntent'> CLICK FOR ENROLL </a>`

in next page say contact.php get values and put in fields.

For example

```
 <?php 
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $title=$_GET['title'];
 $content=$_GET['content'];
 ?>
```

Now put these values in input fields

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="title">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $content; ?>" name="content">
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I have to change id=, title= and content= in order to make them dynamic? As far as I understand every "Click for Enroll" button would return the same values ( in this case: 12, hello world and SomeContent ). Whereas I would like them to return different data based on which row the "Click for Enroll button" is situated.

Comment: i assume you are working inside any foreach or while loop. if so then you can get this data like this

`<a href='/contact.php?id=<?php echo $Mypost->id; ?>&title="<?php echo $Mypost->title; ?>"&content=<?php echo $Mypost->content; ?>'> CLICK FOR ENROLL </a>`

Where $Mypost is some variable or object inside any loop and title, content and id are any key:values in you array or object.